# How can I render a dxf file with Sphere in OpenSCAD

Tags: 3d, rendering, dxf, openscad

I have a rendering problem about importing dxf file.

Rendering success:

- Use linear_extrude() for a dxf file and display a sphere.
- Only use rotate_extrude() for a dxf file.

Rendering fail:

- Use rotate_extrude() for a dxf file and display a 
  sphere.

Here is my source code:

```
module loadFile() {
    rotate_extrude()
        import("import_exercise.dxf");
}

module loadSphere() {
    translate([0,0,-30])
        sphere(10);
}

loadFile();
loadSphere();
```

Here is the error message:

```
ERROR: CGAL error in CGAL_Nef_polyhedron3(): CGAL ERROR: assertion violation! Expr: e->incident_sface() != SFace_const_handle() File: /Users/kintel/code/OpenSCAD/openscad/../libraries/install/include/CGAL/Nef_S2/SM_const_decorator.h Line: 329
```

Here is the scad file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dT84jAzTGn-FxavEXamVivUwODelRqLS/view?usp=sharing

Here is the dxf file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XhjWkydDVEnrn-vYcJOT5-yIjSRtdQaT/view?usp=sharing

[Preview success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXaST.png)

[Render fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDIVw.png)

[Render success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMSCC.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the dxf-file. Your model touches the y-axis in 1 point. Explanation see [in openscad forum](http://forum.openscad.org/Assertion-Violation-in-Render-td10598.html).
I modified your dxf in two ways. In the first the y-axis is not touched by a point but by a shape, in the second the shape is 0.1 mm parallel to y-axis. Both render without error and the resulting design is valid!

[image]

You can download the dxf-files from [box](https://app.box.com/s/q0ncilbqi5nm7fkdq3xyfqv8moxkb7dm)