# CGAL ERROR: assertion violation! Expr: e->incident_sface()

Tags: openscad

I'm trying to combine two .stl files together. Individually each one seems to render ok, but when I place them together I'm seeing this compile error:

```
ERROR: CGAL error in CGAL_Nef_polyhedron3(): CGAL ERROR: assertion violation! Expr: e->incident_sface() != SFace_const_handle() File: /usr/include/CGAL/Nef_S2/SM_const_decorator.h Line: 326
```

When I google this error I see:
[How can I render a dxf file with Sphere in OpenSCAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48217579/how-can-i-render-a-dxf-file-with-sphere-in-openscad)

Which references this: http://forum.openscad.org/Assertion-Violation-in-Render-td10598.html

Based on that it sounds like I need to shift my model off the X-axis, but even when I did that it still seems to be failing. I think I'm miss-understanding the solution. Where should I be looking at to do the X-axis shift?

Here is my code that imports the two stls:

```
import("globe_bigger_windows.stl");

scale=.5;
rotate([0, 0, -1]) {
    translate([0, 0, -5]) {
        scale([1*scale, 1*scale, 1*scale]){ 
                translate([0, -25, -40]){
                import("Dragon.stl");
                }
            }   
    }
}
```

Here is my [repository which holds the stls](https://github.com/sorvis/Christmas-Tree-Ornaments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with the dragon file.

It works individually because it is not actually processing the model until you mesh it with something.

It works after repairing it with MeshMixer, using the "Make Solid" function.

Comment: Thank you I was able to solve the problem doing that. Side tip for others I was able to install MeshMixer in Linux using Wine.